# What is the maximum concurrent connection in RPC?

Tags: rpc

I want to use RPC in a client-server architecture. In test/debug phase, we establish just one remote call-it means that there is no concurrent RPC to the same remote function-, however, concurrent remote call from multiple client are also possible in the future.

several client would call the same remote function, currently. what happen in this situation?
I want to know that is there a bottleneck in RPC due to the maximum concurrent remote call? 
Dosen't RPC reject any remote call, itself, when another client concurrently do RPC on the same function?

Thank you

Comment: I am working on a new Health project. several client would call the same remote function, currently. what happen in this situation.

Comment: It depends on so many factors. What kind of machines, the switches, connection between the machines, the programming language used. When using Go on a Xeon 1245v2 over the internet about 2000. Internally with all the database calls and all that ~5000. per machine. I don't know your case. php with symfony2 ~50.

Comment: As I find, it is relate to the hardware. 
So, is there any bottleneck in RTC itself? Dosen't  RPC reject any remote call, itself, when another client concurrently do RPC on the same function?

Comment: It depends on the language used and how you implement the procedure or function. A procedure is like a function. It has something going in (parameters) and something going out (response). The client sends something like "hello.greet" the server finds the hello.greet function and runs in and returns the results. Usually though there are more than 1 task that is ran at the same time. What is your preferred way?

Comment: Dear dalu, would you please send the rich comment as a reply/answer? because your comments motivate the others to contribute to this thread, definitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented RPC in Linux with the help of rpcgen, for two different architecture, X86-64 & ARM (Raspberry Pi), as client and server, respectively. It work fine when I used my own stress test. I think that dual was right. He wrote "*It depends on so many factors. What kind of machines, the switches, connection between the machines, the programming language used. ...*"